# Добавление маски выбираемого типа файлов в fileUpload

Tags: java, maven, jsf, fileupload, primefaces

Благодаря allowTypes я имею только запрет на загрузку файлов НЕ типа "docx|xml|json". Можно ли добавить как-то маску, которая в диалоговом окне будет отображать только файлы типа "docx|xml|json", а не все?

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{mainBean.uploadedFilesList}"
   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(docx|xml|json)$/"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. У компонента `fileUpload` в `Primefaces` есть атрибут `accept`, в котором можно указать типы файлов, которые должны отображаться в диалоге выбора файла. Следует помнить, что:

- Атрибут `accept` никак не обрабатывается фреймворком, а является лишь подсказкой браузеру. Подсказка осуществляется за счёт добавления в HTML-элемент INPUT атрибута `accept`. Всё зависит от нативной реализации в браузере, от того, как он обрабатывает этот атрибут.
- Атрибут `accept` принимает на вход тип параметров, отличающийся от параметров атрибута `allowTypes`, поэтому просто скопировать из `allowTypes` в `accept` не получится. Для того, чтобы узнать какие параметры передавать, следует ознакомиться со спецификацией HTML-элемента INPUT. Если кратко, то на вход принимается список MIME-типов, либо предопределённые группы MIME-типов. Можно начать ознакомление с [этого ответа на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503561/1341148)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{mainBean.uploadedFilesList}"
              accept=".xml,.docx,.json"/>
```